# How to edit the selected row when a button is clicked?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I was trying to edit the data from the selected rows in datagridview if the button is clicked and put it in the textbox to update the data and what's happening is if I select a row it is directly putted in the textboxes before I click the edit button, but what I want is if I select a row then click the edit button and the data from the selected rows will be putted in the textboxes provided. Can someone help me please.. 
here is my code in datagridview:

`index = e.RowIndex
        Dim selectedRow As DataGridViewRow
        selectedRow = DataGridView1.Rows(index)
        TextBox8.Text = selectedRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
        TextBox1.Text = selectedRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString
        TextBox2.Text = selectedRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString
        TextBox3.Text = selectedRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString
        TextBox4.Text = selectedRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString
        TextBox5.Text = selectedRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString
        TextBox6.Text = selectedRow.Cells(7).Value.ToString
        ComboBox1.Text = selectedRow.Cells(8).Value.ToString
        TextBox9.Text = selectedRow.Cells(9).Value.ToString`

then this is my code in edit button

```
Try
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
        connect.Open()
        cmd.Connection = connect
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_book_info", connect)
        cmd.CommandText = "update tbl_book_info set (Title = '" & TextBox1.Text & "',Author = '" & TextBox2.Text & "',Copyright = '" & TextBox3.Text & "',Publisher = '" & TextBox4.Text & "',Place = '" & TextBox5.Text & "',Copies = '" & TextBox6.Text & "', Subject = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "', ClassNo = '" & TextBox8.Text & "',Registered by = '" & TextBox9.Text & "',Time = '" & TextBox10.Text & "',Date = '" & TextBox11.Text & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Already Updated!")

        MessageBox.Show("update tbl_book_info set (Title = '" & TextBox1.Text & "',Author = '" & TextBox2.Text & "',Copyright = '" & TextBox3.Text & "',Publisher = '" & TextBox4.Text & "',Place = '" & TextBox5.Text & "',Copies = '" & TextBox6.Text & "', Subject = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "', ClassNo = '" & TextBox8.Text & "',Registered by = '" & TextBox9.Text & "',Time = '" & TextBox10.Text & "',Date = '" & TextBox11.Text & "')")
        data = New DataTable()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = data

        da = New MySqlDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_book_info", connect)
        da.Fill(data)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Comment: You dont have to copy the data to text boxes (and then have to copy the changes back) you can edit the data in the grid .  The good thing is that in the DGV the data is typed - integers are integers, dates are dates etc.  Not so in a text control

Comment: Assuming you do want to edit in `TextBoxes` rather than in the grid, what you should be doing is populating a `DataTable` with a data adapter and then binding that to both your grid and your `TextBoxes`.  The current record in the grid will then auto-populate the `TextBoxes` and any changes will automatically be pushed back to the `DataTable`.  You then only need a single call to `Update` on the data adapter to save all the changes in one batch.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).Value()
    x = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).RowIndex
    y = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
    DataGridView1.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    DataGridView1.Enabled = True
    DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).Value = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```